# Have user input within for loop print something, given a certain input, but not pass to the next file

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

So I'm still new to coding and I've got a mess of for loops, conditional if statements, and a couple of while loops. My code loops over files and depending on my input, it moves the files to a location matching my input. However, I would like to be able to prompt the code to simply print a list but not move onto the next file. I've tried placing it into a while loop but whenever the while loop is satisfied, it passes onto the next file.

```
    while True:
        try:
            if "print df" in answer:
                subset_folders_list = list()
                for folder in all_folders_list:
                    if folder.startswith('A'):
                        subset_folders_list.append(folder)
                df = pd.DataFrame(subset_folders_list, columns ['Folders'])
                print(df)
```

But upon an input of "print-folders", it will print my dataframe and move onto the next file because the condition of the while loop is met. How can I get this code to print this dataframe without moving onto the next file. Note that this while loop is nested inside of another while loop inside of a function that is called inside of another loop that is inside of a function. But I think this is the only chunk of code I need to fix in order to implement this feature.

EDIT: other relevant code:

```
    for filename in files_to_move:
       counter += 1
       matching_folders = list()
       iterating = True
       item_words = set(re.split('[. ,_-]', filename.lower()))   
       source_file_path = os.path.join(paths[0], filename)
       all_folders_list = [g for g in os.listdir(paths[12]) if not g.startswith('.')]

       #Matching the filename with a folder
       for folder in all_folders_list:
           count = 0
           folder_words = folder.lower().split(' ')
           for word in item_words:
               if word in folder_words:
                   count += 1
           if count >= 2:
               matching_folders.append(folder)
       #Multiple matching folders
       if len(matching_folders) >= 2:
           print("\n" + f"There is MORE than one folder for {filename}")
           if not filename in files_to_move:
               continue
           while iterating:
               try:
                   pass
                   answer_2 = input("\n" + f"MOVE IT TO ONE OR ELSEWHERE (type name of folder or print-subset for subset list)?: ")
                   item_words = answer_2.lower().split(' ')                 
                   if len(item_words) >= 2:
       #Moving file to a matching or input folder
                       for folder in all_folders_list:
                            count = 0
                            folder_words = folder.lower().split(' ')
                            for word in item_words:
                                if word in folder_words:
                                    count += 1
                            if count == 2:
                                folder_path = os.path.join(paths[12], folder)
                                destination_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                                shutil.move(source_file_path, destination_file_path)
                                print("\n" + f"File moved to {folder}")
                                print(FTG)
                                iterating = False
                                break
                   if len(item_words) < 2:
                       file_mover(source_file_path, paths, filename, answer_2, iterating, all_folders_list, matching_folders, x, counter)
                       iterating = False
                       break
```

So my function file_mover() has many other conditional if statements in it, I will skip them because they work, but the part I want to add is to be able to print the subset without moving onto the next file. Here is file_mover:

```
    def file_mover(source_file_path, paths, filename, answer_2, iterating, all_folders_list, matching_folders, x, counter):
       FTG = str("\n" + str(x - counter) + " files to go")
       while iterating:
          if "exit" in answer_2:
             print()
             iterating = False
             sys.exit()
          if "pass" in answer_2:
             print("Moving on to NEXT file" + "\n")
             print(FTG)
             iterating = False
             pass
          if "del" in answer_2:
             shutil.move(source_file_path, os.path.join(paths[15], filename))
             print(f"File moved to DELETE folder" + "\n")
             print(FTG)
             iterating = False

          #This is where I want the ability to just print something given the input "print-subset", or something like that, and have it re-prompt me for an input.
       else:
           break
```

The reason I want to add this is because there is a subset of non-matching folders that sometimes I want to move the files to, and I don't always remember what they are or I type them in wrong. Now I've got an error catcher in my main while loop, so that could easily function as a workaround for typing in the folder name wrong, but I'm new to coding and this would be good practice. I've tried a lot of things and I can get it to print over and over again endlessly or I can get it to print one time but it moves onto the next file. I don't want either of those to happen. I'd like the subset to print once and have it prompt me for an input again for the same file. I can also try to implement this in the len(item_words) >= 2 section and do the input as "print subset", but I might also run into the same problems.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "move onto the next file"? As written, this code doesn't seem to have any mention of files or moving between them

Comment: you are assigning folders to an empty list with `folders_list = list()` so the loop below that effectively is not executing.

Comment: when I mean move onto next file I mean that my entire code is looping over files. Depending on some parameters, it prompts me for an input, and then moves the file depending on my input. However, I just want to print something within a single loop without the loop continuing to the next iteration.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia that's my fault, I will edit, but folders_list is a different list that is not empty. It is a large list of folders.

Comment: Could we see the rest of the code, and in what way do you want it to stop before reaching the next file? Do you want it to ask for your input again?

Comment: And minor thing but if you want you could replace that for loop with `subset_folders_list = [folder for folder in all_folders_list if folder.startswith('A')]`

Comment: @RolvApneseth other code added to question. And I know there are probably a million things I could do to make it more concise or better. If you have more suggestions I'm all ears! I'd love some advice if you're willing to offer it.